# Como importar e configurar um projeto Maven com servidor Tomcat no Intellij?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Tenho um projeto simples e gostaria de rodar esse projeto na IDE Intellij, mas, acredito que diferente do Eclipse, a IDE exige outras configurações em paralelo a importação.

Gostaria de saber como funciona esse processo de importação.

Obs: Estou usando a ultima versão do Intellij.

Comment: Acho que na versão Community não tem como configurar um servidor de aplicação, somente na versão Ultimate da IDE.

Comment: É na versão Ultimate mesmo! Tenho alguns anos de licença acadêmica.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-and-managing-application-server-integration.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certo. Então você quer duas coisas:

**1. Importar um projeto Maven no IntelliJ:**

1. File > Open > Procure o pom.xml > OK > Open as Project

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**2. Configurar o Tomcat:**

Adicione uma nova *Run configuration*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Adicione uma novo *Tomcat Server* clicando no **+** verde:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em *Application server* configure a Home do seu Tomcat:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na aba *Deployment* adicione o artifact WAR que você deseja executar no server:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na mesma aba você pode mudar o contexto se necessário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Salve tudo e execute sua nova configuração.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou!